# Disable laptop fan completely

Tags: windows, laptop, fan

Laptop model: Clevo p950 hp6
System: windows 10

I need to disable one of the three laptop fans for a certain reason.

I know Embedded Controller manages fans and Has registers that can be possibly written to to do it?

Edit: I found this ! http://rweverything.com/
Ayyy this the stuff i needed in my life. It looks like a brick factory too so double the fun. Also this is what happens when software guy tries to do hardware

Comment: The fans are there for a reason - you should **not** be disabling them.

Comment: I think the registers have a minimum value anyway. He would have to disconnect power, or jam it.

Comment: I have posted an answer but I do agree that fans are there for a reason, if it is a noisy/damaged fan I would recommend looking at replacing the noisy fan particularly long term.

Comment: @DavidPostill Do not worry i know what i am doing. I have a CS degree. I know what fans in a laptop are for. Please dont write just "its dangerous not do it" its useless. It may be true for a general ordinary user

Comment: It shuts down in order to prevent damage if it was left off. The manufacturer would not go to the expense of fitting an unneeded fan. Having a CS degree does not make you a hardware expert.

Comment: You'd be getting less pushback from people if you were less secretive as to precisely why you think you need to do this, & waving your credentials at us isn't impressive, it just smacks of entitlement. You have no idea what credentials are held by the people you are railing against.

Comment: From help "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face**". What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Okay sorry about this but i feel like every question i ever post on stack meets with "Why you do this?" "Its dangerous dont" and things like that instead of actual answers. It raises my blood pressure. I am sorry. The thing is i would even pay for this yet i am unable to find any information on this topic and its so frustrating. I need to test laptop cooling performance without one fan.

Comment: Keepo in mind that your username is New User, which would suggest you are new to Computers. That said, when any expert answers a question, they do not just answers that question for the person asking the question, but for anyone who may search for this question in the future. We want to be thorough, and the more information a user provides that answers the question, the better other people can find the question to begin with, and ensure that they provide an answer that actually helps you. Any user should be warned about doing something that is not supposed to be done.

Comment: @LPChip Hey that's absolutely correct. However i am still stuck without a solution. The problem is gone now but the curiosity is still here.

Comment: @newUser, "I have a degree in CS", well, I've got a PhD in CS, and know very little of PC hardware...

Comment: @vonbrand Fine but you surely must know that fans are here for a reason and without them your computer will probably wont be stable. I dont think anybody even slightly in touch with computer science and computers could not know this and people here assumed i am clueless even though i tried to formulate question in a way to indicate i know what i am doing

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this would be to remove the bottom casing from your laptop, on one side you will have a single fan, the other a double fan. From what I have seen from the insides of this laptop, each fan has it's own power/control cable (3 in total). Just unplug the corresponding cable to the fan you want to disable.

I am unsure of how to do a temporary software hack. But my answer will do what you require.

Single Fan:
[image]

Double Fan:
[image]

Please note, i took screen grabs from here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRF_hdkT5QM

and I was not the person who created this content. All credit for the video goes to them.

Comment: It doesnt work. Embedded Controller recognizes one of the laptop fans is unplugged with a series of beeps and a Shutdown soon after even though all temperatures are ~40ish

Comment: Which tells you they're required. The manufacturers don't put the fans in just because they feel like it. However, given you have a CS Degree you seem to know what you're doing /s so why not just put a jumper on the fan header so it thinks there's a fan attached?

Comment: Well they will be 40ish if the laptop has only just turned on. That's why it shuts down in order to prevent damage if it was left off. The manufacturer would not go to the expense of fitting an unneeded fan.

Comment: @spikeu_richie Of course they are needed. I just need to disable one and that's what i am asking here not if its safe to do. If its of any comfort to you i lift any responsibility from your answer damaging my laptop.  Jesus people stop caring so much about my laptop and focus on solution

Comment: I offered you a solution. Stick a jumper on the fan header so the motherboard thinks there's a fan attached.

Comment: @spikey_richie Sorry, thanks. That is really good idea. Have a great day.