# How to use this software to turn off my laptop fans?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, clevo

I have a a Clevo NP70PNH laptop that has no way to set the fans below 30% even when the cpu is at 40ºc

I found this software that appears to allow for disabling the fans completely http://rweverything.com/

My issue is that I have no idea how to use it for my laptop model and was hoping that someone could point me in the right direction.

PS: I am aware that disabling the fans can result in the destruction of my machine, in my use case i would be using it like this: setting maximum cpu usage to 1% on windows power settings, lower battery settings, only a music file playing in the background, and a timer that will shutdown the computer in 2 hours( i intend to leave it like this while i fall asleep and the 30% fans are too loud for this)

Its my understanding that upon restarting the computer the fans would be working again as normal.

Advice would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Have you tried SpeedFan? https://www.almico.com/speedfan.php

Comment: yes I have tried but it doesnt detect my fans, all fan controls are missing

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1736725/how-to-set-fans-to-0-on-clevo-np70pnh-laptop but that question has not been answered yet. It is unfortunate that SpeedFan does not work, that would make life easier.

Comment: Nasty workaround for a different model here (but I would not recommend it)... https://superuser.com/questions/1530417/disable-laptop-fan-completely see also https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/issues/246 and https://web.archive.org/web/20160708194801/http://voltground.com/haven/threads/69/ so in conclusion it is pretty difficult, even if you have that model laptop (and most of us do not). Oh, and check the BIOS if you haven't already.

Comment: thank you, tbh I am scared of the software itself since it seems like I could brick my machine with one wrong move, and I really dont know what Im looking at (it seems i have to deduce from random numbers the correct settings)